# C++ namespace problem with ARM RealViewICE

Tags: c++, debugging, embedded, arm

I'm using ARM RealView debug 3.1 and I'm unable to watch variables inside functions defined in a C++ namespace, the code works well and is compiled with armcc. Do any of you know a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, arm confirmed this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Are you truly unable to watch variables inside a namespace? What happens when you try?

GDB requires that you explicitly give the namespace ::

I'm not sure what the ARM debugger requires.